# Is this integral continuous?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is $F(x)=\int_{a}^xf(t)dt$ continuous everywhere if 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^x, & \text{if }x>0\\
C,  & \text{if C is constant not equal 1 and }x\le0 ?\\
\end{cases}$$
 This confuse me since I know $f(x)$ is not continuous at $0$ but $F(x)$ is a sum of area which seems always continuous.

Comment: So $F(x)$ is continuous iff $f(x)$ is bounded in [a,x]?

Comment: This is not what the link says. It says $F$ is continuous if $f$ is Riemann integrable. Which is true for your example on every bounded interval.

Comment: (and note: I wrote 'if', not 'iff')